# R metricsgraphics - multiline plots not animated and no legend

Tags: r, metricsgraphicsjs

I am trying to plot a multiline graph. Facing two issues:
1. No Animation
2. Legend not coming up

Below is my code:

```
plotForecast <- data.frame(hourIndex=1:24,testHourP=1:24,d1P=25:48,enerDataP=49:72)

plotForecast %>%
mjs_plot(x=hourIndex, y=testHourP) %>%
mjs_line() %>%
mjs_add_line(d1P) %>%
mjs_add_line(enerDataP) %>%

mjs_add_legend(legend=c("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The legend is ok, it is appearing under the graph.

However the animation seem to be working only when the x axis is in "date" mode.

```
plotForecast %>%
  mjs_plot(x=hourIndex, y=testHourP) %>%
  mjs_line() %>%
  mjs_add_line(d1P) %>%
  mjs_add_line(enerDataP) %>%
  mjs_axis_x(xax_format="date") %>%
  mjs_add_legend(legend=c("X", "Y", "Z")
```

I know it is strange but it works. You could file a ticket to the developers of the package.